# Fast picture viewer for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, image-viewer

Is there any free alternative to [fastpictureviewer](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/)?
I need a picture viewer that is fast (in best case hw-accelerated) with these features:

- fast browsing through many (some thousand) large (80MP) pictures
- zoom to 100% on click to cursor position (zoom on button down, unzoom on button up)

Optional:

- feature to mark pictures (to be deleted later, batch delete)

Not needed:

- any organizing features

Comment: http://www.irfanview.com/  has a slide-show mode, which allows you to press the delete key to delete files as you go. I set it to display full screen & advance to the next image when I press the space key. It seems quick enough to me ...

Comment: http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm is also one of the most widely sued & full-featured image viewers & well worth investigating

Comment: No of them supports the zoom to 100% on cursor, and all are very slow for large pictures (80MP) - i think no one here tried fastpictureviewer

Answer (score 2):

I recommend XNView http://www.xnview.com. I've been using it for 10+ years.

[image: screen shot]
<sub>(source: [xnview.com](http://www.xnview.com/assets/img/screenshots/xnview-win-01.png))</sub>

```
With XnView you can browse, organize, and view your images in numerous ways:

Thumbnail View
FullScreen View
FilmStrip View
SlideShow with FX
Images Compare
etc...
```

Comment: does this have a one-click zoom to 100%? I need it to fast check photos. I click and get 100% zoom on cursor position.

Comment: I am also curious, as I do not see hardware acceleration listed and waiting on Lightroom as @dermoritz pointed  FastPictureViewer claims to be much faster. If you are not going to use Lightroom (or similar) you are looking for that big WOW feature that I am not seeing in XNView. Does it have it?

Comment: @dermoritz Press `*` on keypad for 100% zoom. The photo loads to 100% if smaller than the window. Mouse wheel also works.

Comment: if this zooms to cursor position it would be an option.

Comment: XnView is truly excellent, and has amazing features, but I've never considered it to be fast.  I think it's speed is average, perhaps even a little slow.

Answer (score 2):

Since there seems no real alternative, i started to create one: 
https://github.com/dermoritz/FastImageViewer

The main features are covered with first prototype and it is really fast (i tested with 80MP images and saw no difference to FastPictureViewer).

You are welcome to try it or to contribute.

Comment: Wow, this is more than a recommendation. It's a self written program. Outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

ACDsee once offered a Freeware version (which has no organizing features). From what I know their decoding filter works the same as in current version. It's still one of the fastest picture decoder around:

Here is the link to the latest ACDsee Free version:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Viewers/ACDSee-Free.shtml